# Sortable items MySQL Structure

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a list of items in a file table, which way is the most practical to **sort records based on how the user has positioned them**? There could be possibly hundreds of records per user. Perhaps there is a better way to do this and I've boxed my thinking in?

**Option 1**: I have a table with the order included. I can easily sort by the order column, however when I add a new field or re-order them on the front-end, I may have to update MANY records, *eg: If there are 50 files, changing file_id 1 to position 50, could renumber the order of every row in turn requiring 50 updates..*

```
table: file
file_id | name  | order
------------------------
1       | test  | 2
2       | other | 1
```

**Option 2**: Organize the file table based off an order table. This requires much more work and error checking, and it's a bit more difficult. Yet I would be updating one row with CSV values and transforming them into Arrays to sort the file column.

```
table: file
file_id | name 
----------------------
1       | test
2       | other

table: order
file_order 
----------------------
2,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for **option 1** you could use these SQL requests :

*i added a field `user_id` to your `file` table*

**to make the 50th file as 3rd position:**

```
UPDATE table SET order=3 WHERE id=50 AND user_id = xxx

UPDATE table SET order=order+1 WHERE id>3 AND id<50 AND user_id = xxx
```

**to make the 3rd as 50th position:**

```
UPDATE table SET order=50 WHERE id=3 AND user_id = xxx

UPDATE table SET order=order-1 WHERE id>3 AND id<50 AND user_id = xxx
```